# SonarQube not measuring code coverage with Java 8

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, sonarqube

Here in my workplace we were requested to update, among other things in our projects, the java version specified in the properties (from 7 to 8).

But, after I change the content in the `<java.version>` tag from 1.7 to 1.8 and do a Maven build of the project with

```
clean package install cobertura:cobertura  -Dcobertura.report.format=xml org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar  -Dsonar.projectKey=myproject -Dsonar.projectName=myproject
```

The code coverage goes to 0% (at the page returned after it completes the analysis). All the other measures, like code smells and duplications continue working just fine.

What are possible reasons for this/possible solutions? I tried looking everywhere and no one here knows why this might be happening. Here is some information in the pom.xml of the parent project:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <artifact-version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</artifact-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <layout>ZIP</layout>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I'm not completely familiarized with the inner workings of the projects, or with how Maven works, so I don't know if I'm missing relevant information. I will add more info if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

While we didn't understand exactly the reason for the drop of coverage to 0%, we found out that adding the Jacoco plugin fixes this problem. Just add to the pom:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>default-report</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```